# Use JavaScript to force refresh of assets

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, page-refresh

I've been having trouble with browsers caching assets (static files, like css and js) and not updating them when they are updated on web server. I imagine that web server (IIS 6.0 unfortunately) should report last changed date so browser would refresh, but it's not happening.

I'm thinking on force refresh when web app's version is changed. Maybe store version on a cookie or HTML5 storage (works in IE?) and force refresh when JavaScript sees version is outdated.

Is it reliable to use cookie for JavaScript storage? Or should I use other way?

And how can I use JavaScript to force refresh? Browser's F5 seems to do the job, how can I do that from JavaScript?

Comment: `window.location.reload()`? That's for refreshing the page but I think your problem isn't rooted in page refresh. Maybe set a cache time limit.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to reload the main CSS file on a particular project:

```
   var reloadStyle = function(el) {
       // reload CSS resource without refreshing the whole page
       var updateRandomQuery = function(s) {
           return(s.replace(/nocache=.*$/,'nocache=' + (Math.random()*1000).toFixed()));
       }
       el.setAttribute('href', updateRandomQuery(el.getAttribute('href')));
   }
   // TODO: reload images, etc
   reloadStyle(document.getElementById('MainStyle'));
```

This script can be extended to generically reload all CSS and then go through images and background-images and reload them. It would just need some time, which I don't have right now!

So just to make things clear, it will not work "out of the box" for any other project. But if you understand JavaScript it can give you an idea.

I have mapped this bit of JavaScript to the "Alt-R" key combination using the Chrome Shortkey plugin.